# Linux file creation time. What are the requirement challenges in considering useful atribute?

Tags: filesystems, stat

I find many users are acquiescent to the fact that many linux/unix variants do not support/store the file creation time. Yet, I feel it has some relevance in operations and audit & trail. I see that it is not even an attribute in the

```
struct stat {
          dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
          ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
          mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
          nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
          uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
          gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
          dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
          off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
          blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for filesystem I/O */
          blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of blocks allocated */
          time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
          time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
          time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
      };
```

Obviously, it is a well meaning imposition, from requirements perspective.
Why is this not a valid/reasonable requirement?

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is essentially a discussion topic, not a problem with specific answers.  It'll lead to opinion based debate.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I have not found a more appropriate forum to put forth new requirements . Can you suggest a way.